# FB is not defined - Facebook @ work

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use SDK Javascript with Facebook@work

I am getting FB is not defined.

```
FB.init({
    appId      : '{app-id}',
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.4' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.2, v2.3
  });
```

What do I have to put on the appId fied ? the community ID doesn't work and I can't have any App on facebook@work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to load the JavaScript SDK:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'your-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.6'
    });
};

//load the JavaScript SDK
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Of course you MUST create an App for this: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I thaught I don't need an app when it's about Facebook@Work

Comment: of course you need an app to use/initialize the javascript sdk

Comment: The app is created, I made it public, but still have the same error. FB is not defined

Comment: then you did not load the javascript, as i have explained in my answer. take a look at the code and make sure you understand what it does. also, of course don´t try this by just opening your html file locally without a server.